# LinearLayout Button height should match_parent but with maxHeight, is this possible?

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

My `MainActivity` layout is a `LinearLayout, vertical orientation, which is divided into two halves. The upper half has a weight of 10 and contains an ImageView. The second half is intended for three buttons.

The buttons width should wrap_content, but be at least 230dp wide = No problem.

Now my problem:

I want the height of the buttons to at least be as high as the button needs to be to display the button's text correctly. But! if there is room for more, then the button should be at least 60dp high. How can I manage to do this?

I tried to have layout_height to: wrap_content and minHeight="60dp". but if the screen is too small then one or two buttons might not display/appear on the screen.

So i thought of Height="match_parent" and set a max_height="60dp" instead. but this doesn't do anything. No matter what, each button will cover 1/3 of area.

Here is an explanation with images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmkI1.jpg

I want picture on upper 50% of the screen, the lower 50% contains 3 buttons. where you should at least be capable of reading the buttons text = wrap_content... but if there is a lot of room in the lower 50 %. then the buttons can be a little bit bigger. I cannot manage to do this.

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/sligthly_grey"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_picture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/img_picture"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="20dp">

        <Button
            android:minWidth="230dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn_one"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="Btn one"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:minWidth="230dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn_two"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="Btn two"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:minWidth="230dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn_three"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="Btn three"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Add the expected layout image

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/ljqPRUz.png

the image is quite big. so it should in some manner fit inside the upper half without screwing its dimensions. there might be space around the image...

Comment: Whats this ? its just a White image with text written in center .

Comment: Its an example image with the exact same width and height as the original im using in the application :)

Comment: Do you want it to square on each screen size ?

Comment: I still do not get the problem . Can u pls elaborate with attaching some screen shots  to question .

Comment: ok.. lets look at this image where i explan it: 

https://imgur.com/a/TUkZd

Comment: And the image inside layout should be square ? or it can be of any size ?

Comment: the Image should just fit the upper half but keep dimensions w/h ratio. so its okay if there is "space" around it. in other words it can be any size, as long as it fits inside the upper half.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `scrollview` so that if the screen is small other `buttons` should show up giving the `minHeight` and `minWidth` attributes. Using `Scrollview` will solve your problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_picture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_delete_grey"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="20dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_one"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minHeight="60dp"
            android:minWidth="230dp"
            android:text="Btn one"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_two"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minHeight="60dp"
            android:minWidth="230dp"
            android:text="Btn two"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_three"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minHeight="60dp"
            android:minWidth="230dp"
            android:text="Btn three"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

What i get from question following layout should work as per need .

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/absoluteLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/rounded_square" />

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Button2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Button3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If you want button to be width `wrap_content` use it with left and right `padding` attribute. Below is the output for above.You need to create other layout for landscape mode.
[image]

Comment: in this example. its clear to see that the buttons could be a little bit taller. so if there is room, then minheight="60dp" would be nice. But when in landscape mode, when there probably wont be room for more, the buttons should only at least be as tall as they needs to be to display button text correctly.

Comment: For landscape you need to create separate layout cause in landscape if you use image with fitXY then it will stretch or it not then there will be lots of space left on both sides of image .
And about button height  you can use different dp sizes for height from dimen.xml for all screen sizes .